# Open Graph object with no title doesn't show a link

Tags: object, hyperlink, facebook-opengraph

I'm am successfully posting Open Graph stories without object titles, per the instructions here:
[Objects without titles](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/titleless-objects/)
However, the text in my post is not being linked to my object URL. Even in the instructions there are inconsistencies - e.g. "Alberto Tretti took a photo with Dev Sandbox" - photo is **usually** linked but in the last example on the page it's not - see attached screenshots. How can I make sure there is a link to my object URL? 
[image: object linked]
[image: No link to object]

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is almost a year old, but it was the first google result in my search so I think it deserves an answer. A warning before I begin, I haven't used self hosted objects or objects without titles so this may be wrong but this seems to apply to the rest of the Facebook sharing that I've done. With that said…

In both of the examples you posted there is a link to the object. In the first it is the word "photo" in "Alberto Tretti took a photo with Dev Sandbox." in the second it is the "object title' in the object section underneath it.

By my understanding unless in the open graph story you modify the share text so that it doesn't include the default share text it will always include a link to the object. If you want there to be a link in the text of the post you can modify the "One to One - Without Object Title" post in the story you are using to use some other part of your object, like the description or a custom property.